# High Sierra Insisting on iCloud for File Sharing

Tags: icloud, high-sierra, file-sharing, afp

I have two computers (iMac, MacBook Pro). I am the sole user of both, and I am logged into the same iCloud account on both. Both run High Sierra.

I used to be able to connect from MacBook to iMac via AFP either by clicking the iMac in Finder's sidebar or doing Command+K, afp://username@imac.local/ — and then either way authenticating with my local-to-iMac credentials.

On High Sierra, the MacBook connects automatically using my iCloud ID instead, and then I have no access to anything. If I click "Disconnect", it *immediately* logs in again with my iCloud ID.

How can I ***either***...

1. Disable connecting with this iCloud account (without logging out of iCloud on either machine)

or

2. Grant access for my iCloud account to the directories I want?

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176830/file-sharing-afp-skips-connect-as) looks like the same question, but the answer doesn't seem to work at all (I've always done username@imac.local and it no longer works).

Comment: AFP has been deprecated, have you tried SMB?

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know AFP was deprecated. Trying SMB does seem to work. It still *says* I'm logged in as my Apple ID, but my privileges match my real account, which is all I really care about.